# How to disable animation when entering in PIP mode in android

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture

My PIPActivity has only one image view and I am entering in PIP mode in onCreate() i.e PIPActivity is there only to show image in PIP mode. Now when I am starting PIPActivity there is some animation that slowly transitions into PIP mode. During this transition, the image is getting stretched weirdly. To avoid this how can stop the animation when entering PIP mode? I have already tried

I want it to be like WhatsApp

Comment: "I have already tried" tried what? Generally, when asking questions on this site, it is best to provide as much context as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Implement this code in the launcher activity and NOT in PIPActivity.

*Kotlin Code :*

```
window.requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
        window.exitTransition = null;
        window.sharedElementExitTransition = null;

        setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
```

*Java Code :*

```
getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    
//These functions define the exit transition for the calling activity.
getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(null);

setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
```